# Python: List out of index

Tags: python, list

My code takes in a list like this: `["1.1.2", "1.0", '1.3.3', "1.0.12", "1.0.2"]`. I am simply trying to take the first number before the first decimal point. However, my code is yelling at me saying "List assignment index out of range." Here is my code:

```
def answer(l):
    arr = list()
    index = 0
    for i in l:
        print i
        arr[index] = i.split('.')[0]
        print arr[index]
        index = index+1
    print arr


answer(["1.1.2", "1.0", '1.3.3', "1.0.12", "1.0.2"])
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You cannot add items to an initially-empty list by assigning to nonexistent indexes; use `.append()` instead.

Comment: Or you can initialize an list equal to the length of the passed in list
`arr = [0] * len(l)`

Comment: @user2774695: While `[0] * len(l)` is legal, it's typically considered unpythonic to preallocate like that. The advantage to `append` is that it's self-documenting in and of itself: "I want to put something new at the end of the `list`." Assigning by index (especially a manually adjusted index like this, rather than one generated via `enumerate` or the like) is much less obvious. It's also less exception-safe; if an exception occurs, even if it's handled, it's easy to mistake initial filler values for generated values.

Answer (score 1):

```
def answer(l):
    return [e.split('.')[0] for e in l if "." in e]

answer(["1.1.2", "1.0", '1.3.3', "1.0.12", "1.0.2"])
```

Output:

['1', '1', '1', '1', '1']

Answer (score 0):

on this line `arr[index] = i.split('.')[0]` when you try to access `arr` at `index` 0 at first since the list is empty you get an array out of bound exception.

use `arr.append(i.split('.')[0])`